# What is the disadvantage of allocating a new memory array as a way to dynamically increase its size in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, arrays, memory

Since dynamically increasing in-memory arrays is not allowed in Solidity, I thought about creating a helper method like the below to create a new array with one more element every time I wanted to increase the size. What is the disadvantage of doing this since everything is done in memory? Thank you.

```
contract ArrayTest {
    function test() internal pure returns (address[] memory) {
        address[] memory a = new address[](1);
        a[0] = address(0);
        a = push(a, address(1));
        a = push(a, address(2));
        a = push(a, address(3));
        a = push(a, address(4));
        a = push(a, address(5));
        return a;
    }

    function push(address[] memory a, address addressToPush)
        internal
        pure
        returns (address[] memory)
    {
        // create the new array with one element larger than the passed in array
        address[] memory b = new address[](a.length + 1);
        // copy the old array into the new array
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            b[i] = a[i];
        }
        // add the new element to the end
        b[b.length - 1] = addressToPush;
        // return the new array
        return b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You allocate new memory each time when you add a new item. At some point allocating memory goes from linear costs to quadratic costs, therefore becoming quite expensive.

Answer (score 1):

In short - it's more expensive. How much depends on how often your have to do it. Expanding a small array like this once is no big deal but if you need to do it repeatedly you should look for alternatives.

Here's how it specifically affects gas usage:

- If you could just increase the size in place, it would be `O(1)` complexity in terms of computation because you would only need to write the newly added element. In your method you rewrite every item so it's `O(n)` instead.
- The way you do it in your example is especially inefficient in case you need to add more than one item. Adding `m` items will cost you `O(m * n)` that way. You could do it in `O(m + n)` by defining a function that can add `m` elements in one go.
- Solidity has no memory management/garbage collection so anything you allocate stays there until your call terminates. This matters because there's an extra cost associated with writing to yet unused areas of memory. See [what is expansion cost?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92546/what-is-expansion-cost).