# What is a returnbomb attack?

Tags: solidity, defi, memory, attacks

I've read that when making an external call to an unknown contract, if the contract returns a large amount of random or junk byte it will cause some type of bug. But I dont know exact what it is and how it will be performed.

Can someone provide some more context and/or resources about this attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general issue is that a regular low-level Solidity call, ie `<address>.call()`, will automatically copy all bytes returned by the callee to memory.

Note that using memory during an EVM execution costs gas, more specifically you pay gas [whenever the memory is expanded](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92546/what-is-the-memory-expansion-cost).

A possible DOS vector a caller therefore needs to take into account before calling an unknown contract is a **returnbomb attack** which can lead to the caller running out of gas and the execution to halt.

During such an attack, the callee returns such a big amount of return data that the caller runs out of gas while copying the data into memory.

To prevent such an attack, the caller can use yul/assembly to explicitly decide how much data should be copied to memory.

For more info you may read into `nomad-xyz`'s [ExcessivelySafeCall](https://github.com/nomad-xyz/ExcessivelySafeCall) project.

EDIT: To execute such an attack in a local environment, see [pcaversaccio](https://github.com/pcaversaccio)'s [ReturnBombExample.sol](https://gist.github.com/pcaversaccio/3b487a24922c839df22f925babd3c809) gist.

Comment: @kumar Does this answer your question? If so, could you please mark it as "answered" to help future folks with the same question? If not, anything that's still unclear?